# Java Hashmap is allocating and deleting arrays

Tags: java, hashmap

I have been coding a Chess-engine in Java which is playing decently and is competes with 2050 CCLR engines. I am using a transposition table to store information about different positions.

I usually map a key (long) to an object which contains about 8 ints. I managed to reduce this to 2 ints but this did not solve the problem so I went back to 8 ints for simplicity.

It's important to explain how the hashmap is used:

> Basically when I search for the 'best move' for a position, I clear
>   the hashmap to begin with and it searches and in the meantime, it
>   fills the map. During search, no elements are removed (perhaps
>   overriden). After the best move has been found, the map is cleared.

---

If I run a single search (without clearing the map, the memory usage looks like this):

[image]

I was wondering where these spikes come from. Is this due to the HashMap implementation? What is going on here? I used VisualVM to figure out that many int[] are created and deleted.

---

Usually when testing, I need to run multiple engines at the same time (about 20). What is going on is the following:
I run about 10 games at the same time. An engine takes more time to think at the beginning and therefor uses more heap for the hashmap. But as the game progresses, the engines moves faster. But sadly even if the hashmap is cleared, the heap size doesnt go down.

I was looking for some solution to limit the size of the hashmap but didnt find a suitable solution.

Could someone help me here?

Comment: If I remember correctly the internal array used in a `HashMap` will never shrink, only grow. How many entries do you usually store in a `HashMap` and how long does it live (the whole game? only for one turn?)

Comment: Mhm I guess about 500k entries but it depends on how long the engine thinks.
the hashmap lives for an entire game and is cleared at the beginning of each search.

But the graph displays the memory consumption of a single search where the memory isnt cleared.

Comment: I also think that when clearing the map and even calling the GC manually, the total memory consumption doesnt go down. I verified this using something like this in my hashmap:

if(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() < 1E9){
            return super.put(key, value);
        }

I used this in combination with A) clearing the hashmap after every search, B) setting the hashmap to null and creating a new hashmap. 

Both yielded the same result

Comment: If you are adding a lot of entries to a HashMap (or ArrayList for that matter) it will re-allocate its base table of entries several times (doubling each time) as the number of entries grows beyond the capacity.  So if you plan to put 500k entries in one, use the HashMap(int) or HashMap(int, float) constructor with a fairly large number (I think float =1.0f prevents rehashing).This will cut out the unnecessary re-allocations as it grows, but I doubt explains your problem. Also look out for places where String concatenation is used - switch to StringBuilder.